jQuery multiple forms. Need to catch $(this) forms 'on submit'
I have several forms on a page contain in widget like elements to upload images. There could be one, or there could be 10. Im trying to dynamically, individually catch that particular forms on submit. Here is what I have, but on submit it just refreshes the page. Any ideas how to make this work?
Here is the form:
<form id="med_blog_form_<?=$b['blog_med_id']?>" name="med_blog_form" class="med_blog_form" action="#" method="post">
    <label for="media_blog_file_<?=$b['blog_med_id']?>">
         <div class="btn_sm edit_blog_med_btn">UPLOAD</div>
         <input type="file" id="media_blog_file_<?=$b['blog_med_id']?>" data-blog_med_id="<?=$b['blog_med_id']?>" class="media_blog_file" name="media_upload" hidden/>
         <input type="hidden" name="upload_type" value="blog_media_upload" />
         <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="<?=$blog_id?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="<?=$b['src']?>" />
     </label>
</form>

and here is the jQuery:
$(".media_blog_file").change(function() {

    blog_med_id = $(this).data("blog_med_id");

    this_form = $(this).closest("form");
    this_form.submit();

    this_form.on('submit',(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        alert("form submit "+blog_med_id);
        //do other stuff here...

    })
    )

})


It's not really clear what you're trying to do. If I guess, I'd say you want to trigger a submit event for the form when the file value changes but you also handle that submit event in JS. Does that sound about right?

you are calling submit before the adding event listener

There's a couple of issues here...

Don't register event handlers within event handlers. That's rarely / never what you want to do

You really don't need jQuery for this


Instead, add two delegated event handlers; one to listen for file changes and trigger submit events, and one to listen for form submit events


document.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('input[type=file].media_blog_file')) {
    e.target.closest('form')?.requestSubmit();
  }
});

document.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('form.med_blog_form')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const blog_med_id = e.target.querySelector(
      'input[type=file][data-blog_med_id]',
    )?.dataset.blog_med_id;

    // alert(`form submit ${blog_med_id}`);
    console.log('form submit:', blog_med_id);
  }
});
<!-- note PHP parts have been replaced with static values -->
<form id="med_blog_form_1" name="med_blog_form" class="med_blog_form" action="#" method="post">
  <label for="media_blog_file_1">
         <div class="btn_sm edit_blog_med_btn">UPLOAD</div>
         <input type="file" id="media_blog_file_1" data-blog_med_id="1" class="media_blog_file" name="media_upload" hidden/>
         <input type="hidden" name="upload_type" value="blog_media_upload" />
         <input type="hidden" name="blog_id" value="1" />
         <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="my_file" />
     </label>
</form>




I'm using the HTMLFormElement: requestSubmit() method instead of just .submit() as the latter (in vanilla JS) bypasses event listeners and directly submits the form.
jQuery's .submit() (aka .trigger('submit')) behaves much the same as requestSubmit().

No worries @Chris. I'd probably put the data attribute on the <form>, feels like it would make more sense there

Something to be cautious of: OPs .submit() is jquery $("form").submit() which is different from javascript $("form")[0].submit().   Javascript's .submit() won't trigger submit jquery submit events, while jquery's .submit() will.
